# Error when using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: excel, perl

I get 2 errors when compiling the following code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $xlsparser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $xlsbook   = $parser->parse('xsl_test.xls');
my $xls       = $xls->worksheet(0);

my ( $row_first, $row_last ) = $xls->row_range();
my ( $col_first, $col_last ) = $xls->col_range();

my $csv = '';

for my $row ( $row_first .. $row_last ) {    #Step through each row
    for my $col ( $col_first .. $col_last ) {    #Step through each column
        my $cell = $xls->get_cell( $row, $col );    #Get the current cell

        next unless $cell;

        $csv .= $cell->unformatted();    #Get the cell's raw data -- no border colors or anything like that

        if ( $col == $col_last ) {
            $csv .= "\n";                #Make a new line at the end of the row
        } else {
            $csv .= ",";
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
global symbol "$parser" requires explicit package name at line 8
global symbol "$xls" requires explicit package name at line 9
```

I get the above code from http://www.ehow.com/how_7352636_convert-xls-csv-perl.html, and installed the excel module using: `cpan Spreadsheet::ParseExcel Spreadsheet::XLSX Spreadsheet::Read`

What's causing the error?

Answer (score 3):

Those errors mean that you are using `strict`, but you didn't declare some variables with `my`.  For example, you declared `$xmlprser`, but then you tried to use `$parser`, which was not declared. The code you copied has errors.

A better place to get code is the source itself: [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#SYNOPSIS)

Try:

```
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $xlsbook = $parser->parse('xsl_test.xls');
my $xls = $xlsbook->worksheet(0);
```